# Getting angry while ablution and offering prayers

Tags: salat

I often feel angry and frustrating while performing ablution and offering my prayers. What could be the reason behind that? Its more often after my marriage and relation with my wife is also upset although we both have no financial problems. There is a sudden fight starting between me and my wife over very small issues. Can someone guide me what to do?